# Method to fill the arrays with sequence of integers and print

Tags: java, arrays

I have this question about how to write a method to fill an array with integers. I did this method, but I got confused on how to print it. Should I start with for loop in each method? And how should I print them on one line with a space between each number like this：[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 50]?

```
public class Numbers {
    public int[] numbers;

    public Numbers() {
        numbers = new int[50];
    }

    public void numSequence() { // filling the array with sequence of integers.
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            numbers[i] = i;
        }   
    }

    public void printArray() { // printing the array 
        // do I need for loop here 
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.print(i+1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Numbers d = new Numbers();

        d.numSequence();
        d.printArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is zero more than 50?

Comment: You aren't printing the array, you just print the iteration number plus one in a for loop... Also when do you think 0 is greater than 50?

Comment: Off by one errors are the two most common errors in programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your `printArray` method is not printing the array. It's printing the indices of the for loop. So first of all, print the actual array values.

Also with that print, you can add your own spaces after each letter.

E.g.

```
public void printArray() { // printing the array
    System.out.print("["); // not in loop
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { // loop through numbers array
        System.out.print(numbers[i]); // print the element in the array
        if (i != numbers.length - 1) { // not the last element, so print a space
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("]"); // not in loop
}
```

But then you will run into an issue. Because when you created your `numbers` array, you started at `0`, not `1`. Now, you could fix this by adding `1` to the `numbers` array like you did in your question. But that's bad practice, since you could have just created your array properly in the first place. So change your `numSequence` method to this:

```
public void numSequence() { // filling the array with sequence of integers.
    for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) { // starts at 1, and <= 50 so it adds 50 too
        numbers[i] = i;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to create a class to do this kind of stuff. The example code in Java 8 is something like:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(1, t-> t + 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stream.limit(50).toArray()));
```

If you insist on using the printArray method, please take a look at the implementation of Arrays#toString. Basically you have to use StringBuilder to concatenate the array items.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going in detail ,i will just patch up your code,

```
public class Numbers {
public int[] numbers;

public Numbers() {
    numbers = new int[50];
}

public void numSequence() { // filling the array with sequence of integers.
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        //Add i+1 here o when we print we get 1 2 3 ....50
        numbers[i] = i+1;
    }   
}

public void printArray() { // printing the array 
    // Use numbers.length instead of 50.
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        //Print the values inside the array numbers
        System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Numbers d = new Numbers();

    d.numSequence();
    d.printArray();
}
```

}

**Tip** : You can make the Program more scalable by using this method instead  of yours and access it as d.numSequence(100) this will print 1 2 3 ...100

```
    public void numSequence(int theNumberLimit) {
    for(int i = 0; i < theNumberLimit; i++) {
        numbers[i] = i+1;
    }   
}
```

Thank you hope this helps